# Modify a property of an element that is inside of react state

Tags: reactjs

I have this program that brings an article from my data base in componentDidMount(), fragmentedArticle() grabs each word and put it in this.state.fragmented and each word is put it in a span tag in this.state.fragmentedTags

I print the article in grey color text, but I want to change the style color property of the text (with a setTimeout every 1000 milliseconds) but I don't know if it's posible to changed a property of a tag that is save it in the react state.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class ArticleDetails extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          id: '',
          title: '',
          article: '',
          date: new Date(),
          lenguages: [],
          articles: [],
          fragmented: [],
          fragmentedTags: [],
          showSpans: false,
          counterSpaces: 0,
        }

        this.deleteArticle = this.deleteArticle.bind(this);
        this.fragmentedArticle = this.fragmentedArticle.bind(this);
        this.coloredArticle = this.coloredArticle.bind(this);

    }

    componentDidMount() {

        this.setState({
            id: this.props.match.params.id 
        })

        // get individual exercise.
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/articles/'+ this.props.match.params.id)
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                title: response.data.title,
                article: response.data.article,
                duration: response.data.duration,
                date: new Date(response.data.date)
            }) 
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })

        // get all lenguages.
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/lenguages/')
        .then(response => {
            if (response.data.length > 0) {
            this.setState({
                lenguages: response.data.map(lenguage => lenguage.lenguage),
            })
            }
        }).catch( error => console.log(error) )
    }

    deleteArticle( id ) {
        axios.delete( 'http://localhost:5000/articles/' + id )
        .then( res => console.log( res.data ) );
            this.setState({
                articles: this.state.articles.filter( el => el._id !== id )  
            }
        )
    }

    fragmentedArticle = () => {

        let length = this.state.article.length;

        let word = [];
        let fragmentedArticle = [];
        let counter = 0;
        let p1, p2 = 0;

        for (let x = 0; x <= length; x++) {
            word[x] = this.state.article[x];
            if( this.state.article[x] === ' ' || this.state.article[x] === "\n" ){
                p2 = x;
                fragmentedArticle[counter] = word.join('').substr(p1,p2);
                p1 = p2
                p2 = 0;
                counter++;   
            }
        } 

        // we save each word
        this.setState({
            fragmented: fragmentedArticle,
            counterSpaces: counter,
            showSpans: !this.state.showSpans,
        })

        // we save each word wrapped in a span tag with a property of color grey.
        this.setState( prevState => ({
            fragmentedTags: prevState.fragmented.map( (name, index) => 
                <span key={ index } style={{color:'grey'}} >{name}</span>
            )
        })) 

    }

    coloredArticle = () => {

       console.log(this.state.fragmentedTags[0].props.style.color);
       // I see the actual value color style property of the span tag (grey) but I want to change it on green from the this.state.fragmentedTags[0] to the last word within a x period of time with the setTimeout js method.

       // this code bellow change the color but not one by one.
       this.setState( prevState => ({
            fragmentedTags: 
                // map all the elements
                prevState.fragmented.map( (name, index) =>
                    // with a delay of 1500 milliseconds
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        <span key={ index } style={{color:'green'}} >{name}</span>
                    }, 1500)
                )
            })
       )

    }

    render(props) {

        const displaySpan = this.state.showSpans ? 'inline-block' : 'none';

        const {fragmentedTags} = this.state

        return (
            <div>

                <h6>{ this.state.title }</h6>

                {/* this show/hide the article text */}
                <p onClick={ this.fragmentedArticle }>Show</p> 

                {/* I want to changed the text color one by one within a period of time (velocity, setTimeout) */}
                <p onClick={ this.coloredArticle }>Play</p> 

                {/* Show us the full article (each word wrapped in a span with its property) */}
                <div style={{ display:displaySpan }}>
                    { fragmentedTags }
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, a tag is characters in your markup. An element is part of the document. You're asking about the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be transforming state like that. It gets very difficult to debug your application and makes it much more difficult to do simple things.

Download your articles and save them into state but if you need to make any other changes save it into a new part of state rather than overwriting current state. Most likely you do not need to save transformations into state though.

To answer your question, I would set a timestamp for each article and once its downloaded set a timer that will rerender the article with the new changes if sufficient time has passed.